# TailwindCSS: Own responsive class

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm working with TailwindCSS and I created entity like this:

```
@layer screens {
  @responsive {
    .flex-row-around {
      @apply flex flex-row justify-around;
    }

    .flex-col-around {
      @apply flex flex-col justify-around;
    }
  }
}
```

I've generated stylesheet and now I'm trying to use it:

```
<div class="flex-col-around md:flex-row-around">
  ...
</div>
```

But my styles are not added. What is done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TailwindCSS does not have a `screens` layer. Looks like you're trying to create a new utility, in which case you'd want to use the `utilities` layer.

```css
@layer utilities {
  @responsive {
    .flex-row-around {
      @apply flex flex-row justify-around;
    }

    .flex-col-around {
      @apply flex flex-col justify-around;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the docs for reference:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer

---

P.S. If you want to use the new just-in-time compilation, it will generate the responsive utilities automatically without needed to specify them. This feature is currently experimental, but I have been using it in production for a few months now without issue.

```css
@layer utilities {
  .flex-row-around {
    @apply flex flex-row justify-around;
  }

  .flex-col-around {
    @apply flex flex-col justify-around;
  }
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you show any example of how can I use @tailwind screens directive?

Comment: the `@screen` directive is for when you want to write your own CSS. If you've used media queries before, you can replace these with the screen directive. So `@media (min-width: 640px)` becomes `@screen sm`. It will not generate new utilities, only allow you to use the Tailwind screensizes in your CSS's media queries.

Comment: No, not @screen. I meant "@tailwind screens" like here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind

Comment: I see. By default, all responsive classes are placed at the end of the css. This allows you to overwrite styling at larger screen sizes. For instance, `flex flex-col md:flex-row` will have the flex direction of column at the smaller screen size, and flex direction of row at larger screensizes. This only works since the responsive classes are defined after the base classes. If the responsive classes were defined first, `flex flex-col md:flex-row` would be the same as `flex flex-col`. The `@tailwind screens` let's you define where in the CSS to generate the screen variants.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888535/what-does-tailwind-screens-do