# what does "@tailwind screens;" do ？

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm learning **tailwindcss** recently，and I don't understand the `@tailwind screens;`

[image]
[Offical Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind)

Who can explain it or show the usage ？

Answer (score 0):

In the previous release of Tailwind (v2), `@tailwind screens;` would generate [responsive utility classes](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) at build-time.

**However**, in Tailwind v3, this has [been replaced](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#screens-layer-has-been-renamed) by the more generic directive `@tailwind variants;`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the offical repository test file.
[image]
`@tailwind screens;` is just a anchor where the @media style generated will be injected rather than very end of stylesheet.

`@tailwind screens;` is deprecated since tailwindcss v2.2 certainly. I found the [changelog](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases?q=%40tailwind%20screens%3B&expanded=true#deprecate-tailwind-screens-for-tailwind-variants-in-just-in-time-mode).
[image]